# Are arithmetic operators ever preferable to arithmetic functions?

Tags: r, function, operators

I've noticed there are some instances in which an arithmetic operator (in backticks) acts as if it is an arithmetic function.

Arithmetic operator:

```
> `+`(4, 5)
[1] 9
```

Arithmetic function:

```
> sum(4, 5)
[1] 9
```

Yet the arithmetic operator doesn't accomplish this across vectors like typical arithmetic functions:

```
> `+`(1:5)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Is there ever any instance in which the arithmetic operator is preferable to the arithmetic function?

Comment: I do not understand this question. The unary `+` operator (which is not the same as the binary operator) behaves as documented. Why do you expect it to behave like `sum`?

Comment: @Roland, if `+` were a unary operator in this instance it would only take one operand, which is less than in a summation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To the question in the title, I would say ..often or typically. In R we are often working on columns or vectors in parallel, i,e, the order of the values in a vector matter in the sense of being part of the same case or subject. In your examples you are actually seeing  three different functions in action:

First: the unary '+' operator which basically does nothing when given numeric vectors but would do coercion to numeric when given logical vectors:

```
>  `+`(-3:3)
[1] -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3
> `+`(c(TRUE,FALSE))
[1] 1 0
```

Notice that it does *not* make all of its returned values positive as was stated in one of the comments.

Next: the binary '+` operator:

```
> `+`(-3:3, 0:6)
[1] -3 -1  1  3  5  7  9
```

And finally:  the `sum` function, which is _not_vectorized_ and will collapse all values to the sum of their union:

```
> sum(-3:3, 0:6, c(TRUE,FALSE) )
[1] 22
```

The binary `+` will also recycle arguments (with a warning):

```
> `+`(-3:3, c(TRUE,FALSE) )
[1] -2 -2  0  0  2  2  4
Warning message:
In -3:3 + c(TRUE, FALSE) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

When operating on vectors "in parallel" you will often want to use the vectorized operators and be very much disappointed by the results of sum which can only return a value of length 1. Some functions like `outer` which depend on a functional argument require that the function be vectorized.

```
>  outer(1:4, 5:8, sum)
Error in outer(1:4, 5:8, sum) : 
  dims [product 16] do not match the length of object [1]
> outer(1:4, 5:8, "+")
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    6    7    8    9
[2,]    7    8    9   10
[3,]    8    9   10   11
[4,]    9   10   11   12
```

Others  require that a single value be returned. And some others like 'mapply` are agnostic on the subject.

```
> mapply(sum, 1:4, 5:8)
[1]  6  8 10 12
> mapply("+", 1:4, 5:8)
[1]  6  8 10 12
```

The `Vectorize` can be used to create a version of a non-vectorized function and internally it is using `mapply` to return a different function, but it is limited to non-primitive functions since they do not use argument names in their formals list (so you cannot vectorize `sum`.)

It should probably be noted in closing that these have different precedence for which one can get R precedence rules by consulting `?Syntax`. (The unary arithmetic operators have higher precedence than the binary ones. Functions and parentheses implicitly  would have the highest precedence. I have seen situations where there were surprises due to the higher precedence of user defined functions.)