# What is unary plus / minus in R?

Tags: r

From the Details section of R's [Syntax](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Syntax.html) help page:

> The following unary and binary operators are defined. They are listed
>   in precedence groups, from highest to lowest.
>   [some operators]
>   - +   unary minus and plus
>   [some more operators]
>   + -   (binary) add, subtract

What is unary plus/minus ?

Where is the difference between unary plus(+)/minus (-) and binary addition (+) or subtraction(-) in R?

Comment: You'll want to [read this](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Arithmetic.html)

Comment: Also take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27363663/3521006) by BondedDust.

Comment: Just pointing out that this is not an `R` question - it's a matter of logical definition of operators in any language.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The *arity* of an operator tells on how many arguments it operates. Unary works on a single argument, binary works on two arguments, ternary works on three arguments, etc.

```
-a
^
```

That is an unary minus. It negates the value of the **single argument/expression** that follows it. You might think of it as a function call like `minus(a)` that changes the sign of its argument and returns that as result. Unary plus also exists but it is basically a no-op.

```
a - b
  ^
```

That is a binary minus. It takes the value of its **two arguments/expressions** and subtracts the second one from the first one. You might think of it as a function call like `minus(a,b)` that takes two arguments and returns their difference. Binary plus returns the sum.

---

As noted by @BondedDust, in R (and in other languages that support vector processing) some operators actually take vector arguments and then perform their action on each element separately. For example, the unary minus sign-inverts all elements of a vector:

```
> -(-2:2)
[1]  2  1  0 -1 -2
```

or as a function call:

```
> `-`(-2:2)
[1]  2  1  0 -1 -2
```

The binary minus subtracts two vectors element-wise:

```
> 1:5 - 5:1
[1] -4 -2  0  2  4
```

or as a function call:

```
> `-`(1:5, 5:1)
[1] -4 -2  0  2  4
```

The minus operator in R is a function with two arguments:

```
> `-`
function (e1, e2)  .Primitive("-")
```

When both arguments are present, it performs the operation of the binary minus, i.e. subtracts `e2` from `e1` element-wise. When only `e1` is present, it operates as a unary minus and sign-inverts the elements of `e1`.

The same applies to the plus operator. One has to be careful and to not confuse the plus operator `+` with the `sum` function. `+` operates **element-wise** on one (as an unary operator) or on two (as a binary operator) vector arguments while `sum` sums all values present in its arguments. And while `sum` could take any number of arguments:

```
> sum
function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum")
```

the `+` operator takes only one or two:

```
> `+`(1, 2, 3)
Error in `+`(1, 2, 3) : operator needs one or two arguments
```

Comment: It's probably useful to remind readers that `-3:3` would be a single argument even though it is of length-7. It's also not true that `'+'(-3:3, 0:6)` would return the same value as `'sum'(-3:3, 0:6)`.

Comment: @BondedDust I am not understanding what will be the output of the command `'+'(-3:3,0:6)`? But `'sum'(-3:3, 0:6)` will give the output `(-3,-1,1,3,5,7,9)`. Sound likes `'+'(-3:3,0:6)` has unary + and `'sum'(-3:3, 0:6)` has binary +. Is it?

Comment: @tree: You obviously do not have an R console session handy. You have completely missed my point because you have not executed the code. Both function calls were given the same two objects so this has nothing to do with unary-`+`.

Comment: @BondedDust i have just executed the codes in R.        >'+'(-3:3,0:6)
[1] -3 -1  1  3  5  7  9
> 'sum'(-3:3,0:6)
[1] 21. They are not giving the same object. I am still unable to catch your point.

Comment: Your comment saying `'+'(-3:3,0:6)` was using unary-`+` was wrong (since it was being given two arguments) and the comment that `'sum'(-3:3, 0:6)` was binary was likewise wrong (and tangential as well) since `sum` can take any number of arguments and furthermore it's not one of the infix operators that were being discussed, nor is it vectorized.

Comment: I have not understood one thing @Hristo lliev in your answer. Why have you put the symbol `^` under the command of your two highlighted sentence, i.e.,`a - b` `^`

Comment: @tree, it serves just to highlight the position of the minus I'm talking about. Initially I had the intent to present a single expression with a mix of unary and binary operators and then use the ^ to show which one is what, but then decided to simplify it to two separate expressions.