# dplyr date as.numeric strange behavior

Tags: r, dplyr

I just noticed a strange and interesting bug:

```
as.numeric((Sys.Date()-30)-Sys.Date())
#[1] -30
```

Which is correct. But:

```
library(dplyr)
(Sys.Date()-30)-Sys.Date() %>% as.numeric()
#[1] "1969-12-02"
```

If the `%>%` simply feeds the output into the first argument slot, surely this behavior isn't correct?

Comment: Order of operations? Put the entire section before the pipe in parens. I guess operator precedence is what I meant, not order of operations.

Comment: Or go completely magrittr'esque: `library(magrittr); Sys.Date() %>% subtract(30) %>% subtract(Sys.Date()) %>% as.numeric`. This forces you to put the right order.

Comment: Not a bug, misunderstanding of operator precedence, and misconception of `%>%` as a "pipe everything on the left" magic syntax pixie.

Comment: Hrm. I guess `%>%` really isn't a pipe. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've modified your code to make it reproducible for the future:

```
date <- as.Date("2016-10-18")

as.numeric((date-30)-date)
#[1] -30
(date-30)-date %>% as.numeric()
#[1] "1969-12-02"
```

You may also noticed that placing parentheses can change these results:

```
(date-30)-(date %>% as.numeric())
#[1] "1969-12-02"
((date-30)-date) %>% as.numeric()
#[1] -30
```

The answer is in order of operations as specified on the [Syntax help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html). It states that:

> The following unary and binary operators are defined. They are listed
>   in precedence groups, from highest to lowest.
>
> :: :::    access variables in a namespace
>   $ @   component / slot extraction
>   [ [[  indexing
>   ^ exponentiation (right to left)
>   - +   unary minus and plus
>   : sequence operator
>   %any% special operators (including %% and %/%)
>   * /   multiply, divide
>   + -   (binary) add, subtract

Note here that `%any%` comes before `+ - (binary)`. For the difference between unary and binary operators, I recommend the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27739046/1465387).