# Treat arithmetic operators as functions

Tags: r, function, syntax

I've read that everything in R is function. So I wonder if "+" is a function too
and if we can write something like that:

```
xx <- c(1,2,3)
yy <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

# zz is the sum of the two lengths
zz <- +(if(exists("xx")) length(xx), if(exists("yy")) length(yy))
```

Comment: Just use `sum` instead of `+`

Comment: `+` is indeed a function you just need to add back ticks.

Comment: However, your construct with `if(exists())` doesn't work like you expect inside the `+` function call. Try what happens if one of the variables doesn't exist. You basically do something like  `1 + NULL` then.

Comment: @ Ronald: You are right. I fixed it by changing "if" to "ifelse"

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363480/are-arithmetic-operators-ever-preferable-to-arithmetic-functions)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
xx <- c(1,2,3)
yy <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

# zz is the sum of the two lengths
zz <- `+`(if(exists("xx")) length(xx), if(exists("yy")) length(yy))
#[1] 9
```

To call objects that don't have syntactically valid names (such as the function `+` that gets called implicitly if you do something like `1 + 2`) you need to enclose the name in backticks (`) or quotes (" or ').

See also Section 3.1.4 of the [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html):

> Except for the syntax, there is no difference between applying an operator and calling a function. In fact, x + y can equivalently be written `+`(x, y). Notice that since ‘+’ is a non-standard function name, it needs to be quoted.

In your code you get the error:

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "zz <- +(if(exists("xx")) length(xx),"
```

This is because you don't call the (binary)  function `"+"`, but the unary operator `+`, which doesn't expect function arguments and thus interprets the parentheses as the "arithmetic" operator. A comma is not allowed between those.

Comment: You can also use single or double quotes, `"+"(1, 1)` and `'+'(1, 1)` both work as well as the backticks solution.

Comment: A quibble on your last sentence: There is no "inside" of an operator. The rule is that there are no commas allowed anywhere *except* in separating function arguments.